# Change Y intercept in Poisson GLM R

Tags: r, output, regression, intercept, coefficients

**Background**: I have the following data that I run a `glm` function on:

```
location = c("DH", "Bos", "Beth")
count = c(166, 57, 38)

#make into df
df = data.frame(location, count) 

#poisson
summary(glm(count ~ location, family=poisson))
```

**Output:**

```
Coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   3.6376     0.1622  22.424  < 2e-16 ***
locationBos   0.4055     0.2094   1.936   0.0529 .  
locationDH    1.4744     0.1798   8.199 2.43e-16 ***
```

**Problem:** I would like to change the `(Intercept)` so I can get all my values relative to `Bos`

I looked [Change reference group using glm with binomial family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772775/change-reference-group-using-glm-with-binomial-family) and [How to force R to use a specified factor level as reference in a regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872070/how-to-force-r-to-use-a-specified-factor-level-as-reference-in-a-regression). I tried there method and it did not work, and I am not sure why.

**Tried:**

```
df1 <- within(df, location <- relevel(location, ref = 1))

#poisson
summary(glm(count ~ location, family=poisson, data = df1))
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    ...
locationBeth   ...
locationDH     ...
```

**Question:** How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are modifying the data frame, but in your model you are not using the data frame. Use the `data` argument in the model to use the data in the data frame.

```
location = c("DH", "Bos", "Beth")
count = c(166, 57, 38)
# make into df
df = data.frame(location, count)
```

Note that `location` by itself is a `character` vector. `data.frame()` coerces it to a `factor` by default in the data frame. After this conversion, we can use `relevel` to specify the reference level.

```
df$location = relevel(df$location, ref = "Bos") # set Bos as reference
summary(glm(count ~ location, family=poisson, data = df))

    # Call:
    # glm(formula = count ~ location, family = poisson, data = df)
    # ...
    # Coefficients:
    #              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    # (Intercept)    4.0431     0.1325  30.524  < 2e-16 ***
    # locationBeth  -0.4055     0.2094  -1.936   0.0529 .  
    # locationDH     1.0689     0.1535   6.963 3.33e-12 ***
    # ...
```